# Ошибка: 'no overload matches this call'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

TypeScript выдает и подчеркивает ошибку, но тем не менее, код прекрасно работает без её исправления. Пример кода:

```
import React from 'react';
import QuillEditor, { QuillToolbar } from 'react-native-cn-quill';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

export default function RichTextEditor() {
  const editor = React.createRef();

  return (
    <MainView>
      <EditorContainer>
        <QuillEditor ref={editor} />
        <QuillToolbar editor={editor} options="basic" theme="light" />
      </EditorContainer>
    </MainView>
  );
}

const MainView = styled.View`
flex: 1;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-top: 30px;
`;

const EditorContainer = styled.View`
flex: 1;
padding: 10px;
border-color: #DCDCDC;
border-width: 1px;
background-color: #fff;
`;
```

[image: Код с ошибкой]

[image: Текст ошибки]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `DATA` свойство `id` вероятнее всего числовое, а в `keyExtractor` нужно отдавать `string`, то есть, если сделать так:

```
keyExtractor={(id) => id.toString()}
```

будет ок